# How does a SQL Recursive Query not run into an endless loop?

Tags: sql, recursion

Could someone please explain why the query below will not run into an endless loop? Perhaps, this example from the PostgreSQL website will help:

```
WITH RECURSIVE t(n) AS (
    VALUES (1)
  UNION
    SELECT n+1 FROM t WHERE n < 100
)
SELECT * FROM t;
```

In SQL, `from` is evaluated by `where`. So will we not continuously enter t without ever evaluating the `where` clause?

Comment: to understand recursion you must first understand recursion

Comment: please see my edit

Comment: There are plenty of sites to help walk through the recursive SQL syntax. Your question shows little to no research effort and is too broad for SO.

Comment: alright, I will edit my question

Comment: I'm assuming you're looking at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html The steps about how the recursive CTE is evaluating are listed right below the query from your question.

Comment: Yet another: http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/R/recursion.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing "recursive" in "recursive" queries.
It should have been called "iterative".

There are some differences between vendors but the basic concept is the same:

1. The anchor part (the one that doesn't refer to the "recursive" query name) creates the initial set.
2. The iterative part (the one that refers to the "recursive" query name) is using the last set to creates a new set that now becomes the last set, and so on.
   It stops when it gets to an empty set.

---

And here is an endless query:

```
with recursive t as (select 1 union all select 1 from t) 
select count(*) from t
```

---

Explanation for the OP example

```
Initial set created by the anchor part, `VALUES (1)`: 
1 record, n=1

Sets created by the iterative part, `SELECT n+1 FROM t WHERE n < 100`:
1 record, n=2 (the initial set has 1 record with n=1 so `SELECT n+1 from t` returns 2)
1 record, n=3 
1 record, n=4
1 record, n=5
.
.
.
1 record, n=99
1 record, n=100 

When n=100 the WHERE condition `WHERE n < 100` causes an empty set to be created 
and the iteration stops.
```

---

One way to think on iterative queries:

```
with        t0 as (select ...)
           ,t1 as (select ... t0 ...)
           ,t2 as (select ... t1 ...)
           ,t3 as (select ... t2 ...)
            .
            .
            .

            select * from t0
union all   select * from t1
union all   select * from t2
union all   select * from t3
union all   ...
```

t0 is a CTE with no dependencies in other CTE.
t1 is a CTE with dependency in t0.
t2 is a CTE with dependency in t1 (and only t1!).
t3 is a CTE with dependency in t2 (and only t2!).
etc.

t1, t2, t3 etc.. are declared with identical queries, different only in their   dependencies.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Could you please tie your answer back to the syntax/code of the example I gave?

Comment: in step 2: if t returns the number 1 that is currently the only record in the view, shouldn't it just stop and exit. Why does it continue to step 3? Sorry if I am missing something.

Comment: As long as the iterative query return rows the iteration keeps going. The values returned have no meaning (The query will also stop if the anchor query will result in an empty set)

Comment: So to understand correctly, line 2 in the original example code (aka. the anchor part) will be executed at most once? Also, how does the program know to keep going. In some DBMSs, the word recursive is left out, but recursion still works?

Comment: Not at most once - exactly once. As I said there is nothing recursive here - We're generating the initial set. If it is not empty we're using the initial set to generate the 2nd set. if it is not empty we're using the 2nd set to generate the 3rd set. if it is not empty we're using the 3rd set to generate the 4th set, if it is ...

Comment: what exact line of code is telling the computer to generate the next set if previous set is not empty?

Comment: None. Like other things in SQL, we deal with the 'what' and not with the 'how'. We don't code the loops that implements NESTED LOOPS JOIN. We don't code the hash arrays that implements HASH JOIN. We also don't code the iteration mechanism. This is how it is guaranteed to work and we use it 'as is'.

Comment: ok, I can live with that. So to summarise your statement. Whenever you have a CTE and the name of the view comes up in the second part, the DBMS will "know" what to do? I guess then the next clarification question is regarding the process flow you kindly generated. After each step, one record is returned? However, where is the record after each step saved? In some intermediate view or in the main view?

Comment: (1) Basically yes. There are providers that supports multiple anchor/iterative parts so it is not about the location but about referencing/not referencing the CTE name. (2) The sets can hold any varying number of rows (but if it is 0, the process is stopped). In your example it happens to be  a single record for all sets  (3) The sets are being spooled out in a similar way to a standard query such as SELECT ... UNION ALL SELECT ... UNION ALL SELECT ... UNION ALL ...

Comment: ah ok that makes more sense. So basically the union all along with the following select are repeated over and over no? I almost got it. However, I am still wondering how for example the first step gets the value 2. We have not updated n. After all we simply selected (n+1), making it 2. Perhaps the answer is that basically the Select statement somewhere deep down the recursive line uses the result of the previous select? If that is the ok, is there something in the syntax telling it to do so or is the answer again that is "simply works that way"?

Comment: We execute the anchor part. We get a table named 't' that has 1 record with n=1. We now execute the query `SELECT n+1 FROM t WHERE n < 100`. What do we get?

Comment: sure, we now get 2. Is that added to the table 't' or is it saved in the intermediate table in that moment. If it is saved in the table, will the third step not base its (n+1) calculation base its step on both the numbers 1 and 2? Essentially, we would get the value 2 again no?

Comment: We have a new table called 't' that has 1 records with n=2. (the previous 't' was already outputted)

Comment: so in the end, we have 100 tables each with one record and then these hundred tables with one record each are joined?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129473/discussion-between-dudu-markovitz-and-kevin-wu).